# Python: socket connection still open

Tags: python, sockets, bots, irc

I've read some questions on this topic here, but i couldn't get an simple answer.
I'll provide some code so it can be easier.

```
import socket

irc = socket.socket ( socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM )

irc.connect((network, port))

# Do the rest of the connection (set nick, user, join chan)
# Okay, now we're connected

while True:

    doAllTheBotStuff()
```

I have a `!quit` command that breaks the `while True:` loop. But sometimes i get disconected for other reasons, like ping timeout, or my internet crashes. What I wanted to do is:

```
while True:

    doAllTheBotStuff()

    if not stillConnected():
        break
```

How can i do that `stillConnected()` function ?

---

Read/Write:

I've made a class for my bot, but hopefully you can understand it without all that information

```
# READING 

ready = select.select([self.irc], [], [], 1)
if ready[0]:
    temp = self.irc.recv(4096)
    # Here I handle the reading. Parse commands and all that stuff.
```

The writing is always a response to what is read. I use this function:

```
def send_irc_cmd(self, cmd, args):
    self.irc.send(cmd+" :"+args+"\r\n")
```

Comment: Disconnection would usually be detected either by an EOF when you read from the socket, or if a `socket.error` is raised. You'll need to include the code which does the socket reading/writing.

Comment: I'll include a piece of it in the question

Comment: Updated, if you need any detail ask me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* all you need to do is to add something after the line...

```
temp = self.irc.recv(4096)
```

...that checks if `temp` is the empty string, which indicates the remote host has closed the connection, and use that to break out of your loop.

I can't really be more accurate or specific because your code sample is incomplete, and/or a simplification of the actual code.